# Continuity of sin(1/x) when f(x)=0 at x=0 and when at x=0 f(x)=1.

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to prove that the function: $f(x) = \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
    \sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) & \text{for } x \neq 0 \\
    0 & \text{for } x = 0
\end{array}
\right. $
is continuous. I have attempted a proof as below and would like some clarification. I also had the question as to what changes when I define $ f(x) $ differently, for example, $ f(x) = \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
    \sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) & \text{for } x \neq 0 \\
    1 & \text{for } x = 0
\end{array}
\right. $.

Let $c=0$,

then $|x-0|<\delta$ implies $|x|<\delta$

$|\sin(1/x) - f(0)| = |\sin(1/x) - 0| < \varepsilon$

$|\sin(1/x)| \leq 1 \leq \varepsilon$

$|\sin(1/x)| \leq 1 < \delta/|x| = \varepsilon$

$\delta = \varepsilon |x|$

Let $c \neq 0$,

$|x-c| < \delta$

$|\sin(1/x) - \sin(1/c)| < \varepsilon$

$|\sin(1/x) - \sin(1/c)| \leq |\sin(1/x)| + |- \sin(1/c)| \leq 2 < \delta/|x-c|$
(using triangle inequality)

$\delta/|x-c| = \varepsilon$ then $\delta = \varepsilon/|x-c|$

$\blacktriangle$ I would like to know if I have shown $\sin(1/x)$ is continuous.

$\blacktriangle$ I understand that where the function is not defined, so at $x=0$, it is not continuous, but in the first part of my attempted proof, I do not know what incorrect step/oversight I have made?

$\blacktriangle$ Additionally, if I define the function to be $1$ at $x=0$, does this allow continuity everywhere then?

Comment: Does this look continuous at $x=0$? https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot%28sin%281%2Fx%29%2C+x%3D-1..1

Comment: This is very difficult to read. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: $|\sin 1/x \pm\sin 1/c|\le |1/x|+|1/c|$ but $ |1/x|+|1/c|$ is unbounded as $x,c\to 0.$

Comment: I do not understand why you want to reopened this question after so long without understanding the answer you accepted. There is no way to define this function at $0$ to make it continuous. You will see that if you draw a picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you did proves nothing, because $\varepsilon$ can be *any* number greater than $0$, but you wrote that $1\leqslant\varepsilon$.

Yes, $f$ is undefined at $0$. So, it makes no sense to ask whether or not it is continuous (or discontinuous at $0$).

And if you extend $f$ to $\Bbb R$ defining $f(0)=1$, then $f$ will till be discontinuous at $0$, since $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{\pi n}=0$, and therefore $\lim_{n\to\infty}f\left(\frac1{\pi n}\right)=0$. But if $f$ was continuous at $0$, you should have$$\lim_{n\to\infty}f\left(\frac1{\pi n}\right)=f(0)=1.$$